# Model-View-Controller (MVC) Which component handles save/load operations?

Tags: mvc, io

In a traditional MVC application, which component (model, view, or controller) is responsible for reading/writing the model to/from disk?

Answer (score 11):

The Model is generally responisble to reading from/writing to the file system or database.

Comment: The model will usually implement a Multitier Architecture and the lowest tier will write to database.

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij I've edited out the link from your comment, it was pointing to the English Theater of Rome and was flagged as spam. Obviously a copy paste mistake, but be a bit more careful in the future, we are extra vigilant with spammers, I read all your past comments and several of your answers to see if there were other traces of spam like activities.

Comment: @YannisRizos sorry, that was a silly mistake! :) However I was a spammer, I would not have 500 reputation here and 750 on StackOverflow, would I?